# Adding the last line of code results in this error: "in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err". What causes this error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to subset the Dates from 2013 to 2018 and adding the last line of the code [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE5iP.jpg) results in this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKkbd.jpg).

Why does this happen and can anyone tell me if there is a better way to subset the Dates ?

ERROR :

```
File "C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\MTE\Fitness Tracker\Analyze Your Runkeeper Fitness Data\datasets\Fitness Data.py", line 29, in <module>
    datesss=df_run[(df_run['Date'] > '01-01-2013') & (df_run['Date'] <= '31-12-2018')]
  File "C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: Please paste your code NOT, images of it , [edit] your post and add your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct, can you please check when you are creating df_run Dataframe from df_activities, it has 'Date' column and not index else you will have to reset_index().

Error suggest that the DataFrame(df_run) either does not contain 'Date' column or it is set as index.

Boolean mask can be used, works with date as object type or with TimeStamp type:

**Solution**

```
mask = (df['Date'] > '01-01-2013') & (df['Date'] <= '31-12-2019')
df.loc[mask]
```